# How to make RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have  studentPage.php file which shows us Student's info

i want RewriteRule to make this:

```
example.com/students/John-3
```

form this:

```
example.com/studentPage.php?name=John&id=3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (students)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z-]+)$ student.php?name=$3&id=$2
```

Comment: Can get rid of group on `students`, then can use references 1 and 2.